# Python:PostgresSQL: Need to understand Connection commit behavior in Python cursors using Python:Pyscopg2

Tags: python, postgresql

I am trying to understand the behavior of connection commit in cursors.

I have 3 tables named tbl1 ,tbl2 and final_tbl in PostgreSQL DB ,all of the tables has only one column (called col).

col in tbl1 and tbl2 has the initial value of 1 and 1 respectively. final_tbl has col as 0 .

**tbl1**

```
col  1
```

**tbl2**

```
col  1
```

**final_tbl**

```
col  0
```

I am using psycopg2 to push queries in postgres via python.
Code Block :-

```
import psycopg2
q1 = """update tbl2 set col= tbl1.col+2 from tbl1 where <join condition>"""
q2 = """update final_tbl set col= tbl2.col+2 from tbl2 where <join condition>"""
db_conn = psycopg2.connect(host="xxxxx",
                           port="xxxxx",
                           dbname="xxxx",
                           user="xxxxx",
                           password="xxxxxx")

db_cursor = db_conn.cursor()
print('INFO: cursor opened')
try:
    db_cursor.execute(q1)
    db_cursor.execute(q2)
    db_conn.commit()
except (Exception, psycopg2.Error) as e:
    db_conn.rollback()
    raise
finally:
    db_cursor.close()
    db_conn.close()
```

Please Note:- db_conn.commit() is only called once.
I am trying the understand the behavior of the commit() and in view of that which out of the below statements is true .

Scenario 1:-

a>First 3 is set to tbl2 col by db_cursor.execute(q1)

b>Second 5 is set to final_tbl by db_cursor.execute(q2)

Scenario 2:-

a>First 3 is set to tbl2 col by db_cursor.execute(q1)

b>Second 3 is set to final_tbl by db_cursor.execute(q2) as I haven't committed the previous transaction still and only doing at the last .

Appreciate Your help in advance.

Comment: q2 uses the new value for `tbl2.col` because it runs in the same transaction as q1. If you ran q2 in a different transaction, then it wouldn't see the new value until after the first transaction had been committed.

Comment: excellent @Alasdair .My tests also are suggesting the same but your comments made it clear.Thanks for the help